# How to get RequestDispatcher parameter in forward target html

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, requestdispatcher

guys, I want to pass values from one html page to another. In test1.html, submit the value to Serlvet. In servlet got the value, and dispatcher request to test2.html. like this:

```
request.setAttribute("url", url);
request.getRequestDispatcher("test2.html").forward(request,reponse);
```

So, how can i get the "url" value in test2.html?. need help, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
request.setAttribute("url", url);
request.getRequestDispatcher("test2.jsp").forward(request,reponse);
```

then test2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
${url}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this mean can't use method above to pass values to html? (as the forward is server-side) @EJK

Comment: Yes, you can't by using request.setAttribute("url", url);

Comment: Correct.  HTML files are served by web servers.  Web servers only provide static content.  If you want dynamic content (i.e. this case), then you need something served by an application server.

Comment: okay, i see, guys. so what's the common method of pass variables between two html pages?  By variables, i mean, like string, image, file etc. I tried cookies before, but this only for the string case.

Answer (score 0):

As the forward is entirely server-side, the attribute should still be present in the request.  So from test2.html (actually you should make this a JSP page, test2.jsp), you can do the following:

```
<%
String url = (String)request.getAttribute("url");
%>
```

And if you wish to display it:

```
<html> ...
    The URL is: <%=url%>
</html>
```